# authenticaion without private key

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

My goal is to eliminate the private key - authentication.

I have an android application in which I connect to my google cloud virtual instance and run a couple of scripts. Now, I have the private key on the phone for testing purposes so I can connect to google cloud and do what I wrote. My question is:

How could I eliminate the private key thus making the connecting less secure but easier to test on more phones?

My final goal is to send an email to an email address and this runs the scripts on the google cloud virtual instance. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: SSH has authentication methods other than private keys. You haven't described your software at all, so it's hard to understand what kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the ssh configuration file and set `PubkeyAuthentication` to `no` in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

Then you need to restart the ssh server in order to load the new configuration: For Ubuntu: `sudo service ssh restart`, for Centos: `sudo service sshd restart`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It seems useful, tomorrow I will check it out and if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I did not find PubkeyAuthentication  in sshd_config but I found the followings: #   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
As you can see all are commented out. Which one should I uncomment or modify to eliminate the private key - authentication? Thanks

Comment: Your server must have its settings overriden. I suggest asking the question on https://serverfault.com/ and don't forget to mention you are using google cloud.